# Creating multiple pandas dataframes from a single dataframe based on iteration

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, iteration

From a single dataframe(tr), I'm trying to create multiple dataframes based on a set of columns(cat_col). New dataframe names must be tr_'colname'.
Could someone help me with the below code?

```
for col in cat_col:
    tr_ = tr[[col,'TARGET']].groupby([col,'TARGET']).size().reset_index(name='Counts')
    tr_ = pivot_table(tr_,values='Counts',index=[col],columns=['TARGET'])
    print tr_.shape
```

Output:
(3, 2)
(7, 2)
(8, 2)
(5, 2)
(6, 2)
(6, 2)
(18, 2)
(7, 2)
(58, 2)
(4, 2)
(3, 2)
(7, 2)

```
tr[['col1','TARGET']].head(10)
```

col1  TARGET
0    Unaccompanied       1
1           Family       0
2    Unaccompanied       0
3    Unaccompanied       0
4    Unaccompanied       0
5  Spouse, partner       0
6    Unaccompanied       0
7    Unaccompanied       0
8         Children       0
9    Unaccompanied       0

```
tr_col1.head(3)
```

TARGET                0      1
col1
Family            37140   3009
Spouse, partner   10475    895
Unaccompanied    228189  20337

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Please let me know if it makes sense now. I can see dataframes are being created when I try to print within 'for' loop. I just don't know how to create a new dataframe inside the loop

Comment: Why do you think `tr_ ` is not `DataFrame`? It is `DataFrame`, test it by `print (type(tr_))`

Comment: tr_ is a DataFrame but it gets replaced everytime on iteration and stores the values only for the last column.

Comment: Not sure if understand, if uses my sample `tr = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefabcd'),
                   'B':list('abcdeabffe'),
                   'TARGET':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]})` what need as expected output?

Comment: I just checked your sample and code. I was thinking of a way to store d['A'] as tr_A, d['B'] as tr_B but using a dictionary helps to store the values and retrieve it more easily! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
tr = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefabcd'),
                   'B':list('abcdeabffe'),
                   'TARGET':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]})

print (tr)
   A  B  TARGET
0  a  a       1
1  b  b       1
2  c  c       0
3  d  d       0
4  e  e       1
5  f  a       0
6  a  b       1
7  b  f       1
8  c  f       0
9  d  e       1

cat_col = ['A','B']

d = {}
for col in cat_col:
    tr_ = (tr[[col,'TARGET']].groupby([col,'TARGET'])
                            .size()
                            .unstack()
                            .reset_index()
                            .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
    #some another processes if necessary

    #check if outout is DataFrame  
    print (type(tr_))

    print (tr_)
    #if necessary store to dict
    d[col] = tr_
```

---

```
#select df from dict
print (d['A'])
   A    0    1
0  a  NaN  2.0
1  b  NaN  2.0
2  c  2.0  NaN
3  d  1.0  1.0
4  e  NaN  1.0
5  f  1.0  NaN
```